# Solr string field maximum length

Tags: solr, solrcloud

My solr has a definition for an this field type:

**managed-schema.xml**

```
 ...
 <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="lowercases" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 ...
```

Whenever I try to index a document with this field's value too large i get an exception.

I can't seem to find what is the size limit for this kind of field.
The only thing I can find is the property `"maxFieldLength"` which is said to be removed in `Solr 4.0`.

Any way of telling what is the limit?

Comment: is the lowercases fieldType is of StringType...? Can you change the fieldType to textField like <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"/>

Comment: can you share the fieldType lowercases...?

Comment: If you are using string type it would have some limitation on the length...try with textFieldType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct "maxFieldLength" which is removed in Solr 4.0.

To get similar behavior, include a 
         LimitTokenCountFilterFactory in your fieldType definition.

```
<filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/>
```